# Getting ArrayList Value Inside An ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a problem with pulling out a value from an `Arraylist` inside an `Arraylist`.
I'll just give an example of my problem.

Example:

```
ArrayList alA = new ArrayList();
ArrayList alB = new ArrayList();

alA.add("1");
alA.add("2");
alA.add("3");

alB.add(alA);

System.out.println(alB.get(0));
```

This will return `[1, 2, 3]` as the result.

In my case I only need to print out `3`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: alB.get(0).get(2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get value from 2d arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154120/how-to-get-value-from-2d-arraylist)

Comment: You need to use generic first like @Mureinik's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `get` on the inner array:

```
System.out.println(((List) alB.get(0)).get(2));
```

Note that by using generics, you'll eliminate the need to cast:

```
List<String> alA = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> alB = new ArrayList<>();

alA.add("1");
alA.add("2");
alA.add("3");

alB.add(alA);

System.out.println(alB.get(0).get(2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply do the following if you don't want to change your other portions of current code

```
System.out.println(((ArrayList)alB.get(0)).get(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(alB.get(0));` return `alB`'s 0th index element which is `alA`. Since you want the element `3`, you need to get the 2nd index element of `alA`, in this case it is `alA.get(2);`

Combined:

```
System.out.println(((ArrayList)alB.get(0)).get(2));
```